# How do you grep from within emacs ( git grep 'foo' | grep baa )

Tags: emacsclient, git, terminal-emacs, grep

I do this often after shelling out to bash

```
$ git grep 'banner-image' | grep mb3
```

Can I do it without leaving emacs?

Comment: `M-x grep` followed by the input `grep -nH -e banner-image | grep mb3 RET`. (The `grep -nH -e` is provided by default.) As usual for `M-x grep`, this gives you a `grep` output buffer with the search hits. See (emacs) [Grep Searching](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html).

Comment: Is your solution "recursive", because git grep is recursive by default

Comment: Use `rgrep` if you want recursive`.

Comment: the .git folder contains two thousand files not for human consumption. git grep by default ignores that folder. does your solution take that in to account.

Comment: Try `grep-find-template`.

Comment: @joshsverns: Did you try `rgrep`? By default it ignores any/all of `grep-find-ignored-directories` and `grep-find-ignored-files` (see which variables).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633490/how-can-i-use-m-x-rgrep-with-the-git-grep-command-in-emacs

Answer (score 1):

I have counsel (and ivy and swiper and ivy-hydra) loaded, and have "ctrl-c j" bound to `counsel-git-grep`, which works well for the LHS of your pipeline. It is not clear if the RHS of your pipeline is trying to match more of the line or the filename. If the former then I would tend to add a space and mb3, if the latter then I would use "ctrl-c ctrl-o" `ivy-occur` to save the git grep output in a buffer, and then use "ctrl-s" to search this new buffer for mb3, pressing enter to visit the place.

All of these packages are available from melpa.org.