# Advanced git grep from within emacs

Tags: git, grep, emacs25

I've been playing with `vc-git-grep` as pointed to by this answer
[How do you grep from within emacs ( git grep 'foo' | grep baa )](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35255/how-do-you-grep-from-within-emacs-git-grep-foo-grep-baa)

I have a special requirement like this:

```
$ git grep -e 'include' --and -e Image

components/core/app/models/contact.rb:  include HasImage
components/core/app/models/opportunity.rb:  include HasBannerImage
components/core/app/models/organization.rb:  include HasImage
components/core/app/models/organization.rb:  include HasBannerImage
$
```

Is it possible to do that with emacs vc-git-grep ?

I tried

```
-*- mode: grep; default-directory: "~/" -*-
Grep started at Wed Sep  6 06:59:56

git --no-pager grep -n -e Image -- *
Gemfile.lock:70:      rails-assets-Imagesloaded (= 4.1.1)
Gemfile.lock:362:    rails-assets-Imagesloaded (4.1.1)
...
```

To summarize, my question is, is it possible to manipulate the parameters passed to the git grep command?

Comment: You should look at the counsel package. The commands counsel-rg and counsel-git-grep are great. counsel-projectile-rg is another really good one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. It seems M-x grep is pretty powerful, in that it can handle any "grep like" shell command's output.

So you can do

```
M-x grep
# it will ask you for the command, paste this
git --no-pager grep -n -e 'include' --and -e Image
```

and voila!

Comment: You might consider customizing `grep-command` if this is the standard way you want to use `M-x grep`

Answer (score 2):

This feature has been recently added to Emacs (see [this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit?id=e3661f8c35b3057c58e8c0b474f597697ce413ba) commit), and will probably be out on version 27.

The NEWS entry is:

> *** New customizable variable 'vc-git-grep-template'.
>   This new variable allows customizing the default arguments passed to
>   git-grep when 'vc-git-grep' is used.

Refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `vc-git-grep-template` for usage.

Comment: Right now this is a link-only answer, and risks being deleted. Could you explain here how to use it? It's ok if the functionality isn't released yet.

Comment: @zck, Have fixed that.